# Spliting large imported text file into a dynamic 2d array in VB 2015

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am currently trying to code a way to read a text file filled with LOTS of data and create a dynamic 2d array to hold each numeric value in its own cell. The text file has data formatted like this

150.00  0.00030739  0.00030023  21.498  0.00024092

150.01  0.00030778  0.00030061  21.497  0.00024122

150.02  0.00030818  0.00030100  21.497  0.00024151

150.03  0.00030857  0.00030138  21.496  0.00024181

150.04  0.00030896  0.00030177  21.496  0.00024210

150.05  0.00030935  0.00030216  21.496  0.00024239

where the spaces are denoted by a vbTab. This is what I have so far.

```
    Dim strfilename As String
    Dim num_rows As Long
    Dim num_cols As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer


    strfilename = "Location of folder holding file" & ListBox1.SelectedItem

    If File.Exists(strfilename) Then
        Dim sReader As StreamReader = File.OpenText(strfilename)
        Dim strLines() As String
        Dim strLine() As String

        'Load content of file to strLines array
        strLines = sReader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)

        'redimension the array
        num_rows = UBound(strLines)
        strLine = strLines(0).Split(vbTab)
        num_cols = UBound(strLine)
        ReDim sMatrix(num_rows, num_cols)

        'Copy Data into the array
        For x = 0 To num_rows
            strLine = strLines(x).Split(vbTab)
            For y = 0 To num_cols
                sMatrix(x, y) = strLine(y).Trim()
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

When I run this code I get only the first number in the first column of the array and everything else is missing. I need something that shows all of the values. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Edit:
Here's a picture of what I'm seeing.

[What I'm Seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdtD0.png)

Comment: How big is this file. Reading everything in memory could not be a good idea

Comment: 1) Unless you have a reason to hold the data in an array, you could be better off creating a class to represent the data, then having a List of that class. 2) You can use `strLines = File.ReadAllLines(strFilename)` to read into the array in one command. 3) If not using 2) then you forgot to `.Close()` and `.Dispose()` the StreamReader.

Comment: @Steve - The text file I'm using is around 700 KB. I'm not sure if that would cause performance issues

Comment: Something is not as it seems. I have tested your code with a sample file using your data and adding the correct tab separator between numbers. Your code works. Check again if you have correctly the tab between numbers and if you have a standard newline for Windows

Comment: No 700KB should be fine albeit it depends on many factors

Comment: @AndrewMorton - The only reason I'm putting this data in an array is I need to read through the data step by step to find values to interpolate later on in another form so a dynamic 2d array filled with the data seemed to be the best way to do that. How would you go about this in a class form, I'm still fairly new to VB

Comment: @Steve - Something sure is amiss here. I went an edited the text file to make sure that there was one tab between values and a new line is properly created. I still can't seem to create the array I need.

Comment: Step through your code. Does strLines look as you expect? Does strLine look as you expect?

Comment: @JerryM - I've found that strLine only creates one column as opposed to the five I was expecting. I changed that line to strLine = strLines(0).Split() and everything worked just fine. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Steve Thank you for your advice, It helped greatly

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for your help, I'll look into the class method just in case the array method falls through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read all the data in one lump - you can read it line-by-line and process each line.

I assume that the data is machine-generated so that you *know* there are no errors. I did however put in a check for the required quantity of items on a line.

I copied the data you gave as an example and edited it to change the spaces to tabs.

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Class Datum
        Property Time As Double
        Property X As Double
        Property Y As Double
        Property Z As Double
        Property A As Double

        Sub New(t As Double, x As Double, y As Double, z As Double, a As Double)
            Me.Time = t
            Me.X = x
            Me.Y = y
            Me.Z = z
            Me.A = z
        End Sub

        Sub New()
            ' empty constructor
        End Sub

        Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("(T={0}, X={1}, Y={2}, Z={3}, A={4}", Time, X, Y, Z, A)
            ' if using VS2015, you can use the following line instead:
            ' Return $"T={Time}, X={X}, Y={Y}, Z={Z}, A={A}"
        End Function

    End Class

    Function LoadData(srcFile As String) As List(Of Datum)
        Dim data = New List(Of Datum)

        Using sr As New StreamReader(srcFile)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream()
                Dim thisLine = sr.ReadLine()
                Dim parts = thisLine.Split({vbTab}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                If parts.Count = 5 Then
                    data.Add(New Datum(CDbl(parts(0)), CDbl(parts(1)), CDbl(parts(2)), CDbl(parts(3)), CDbl(parts(4))))
                End If
            End While
        End Using

        Return data

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim src = "C:\temp\testdata2.txt"
        Dim myData = LoadData(src)

        For Each datum In myData
            Console.WriteLine(datum.ToString())
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

As you can see, if you use a class to hold the data then you can usefully give it other methods like `.ToString()`.

[Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) makes sure that you do not do anything which is meaningless, like trying to store a string in a numeric data type. It is strongly recommended that you set Option Strict On as the default for all projects.

Option Infer On lets the compiler figure out what data type you want when you use something like `Dim k = 1.0`, so you don't have to type `Dim k As Double = 1.0`, but note that if you used `Dim k = 1` it would infer `k` to be an Integer.

Once the data is in instances of a class in a list, you can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to process it in a fairly easy-to-read fashion, for example you could do

```
Console.WriteLine("The average X value is " & (myData.Select(Function(d) d.X).Average()).ToString())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. I didn't even think you could use this method like this. Even though I figured out what I needed to do for my 2d array, I'm going to implement this into my project and see how it works by comparison. Thanks again for your help.